# NullPointerException while passing an InputStream to Soundbank of MidiSystem in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream, ioexception, javax.sound.midi

I am trying to create a soundbank by reading from a file and passing it onto the `getSoundbank` function of `MidiSystem.` For this purpose, I have to read the file as `InputStream` for which I tried the following techniques but failed.

First technique -- reading the file using `FileInputStream` and passing it to the above mentioned function as follows:

```
InputStream audioSrc = new FileInputStream(file_path);
Soundbank soundbank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(audioSrc);
```

It fails with `mark/reset exception`

Then, I tried the technique mentioned in this thread:
[java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported Java Audio Input Stream / Buffered Input Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580025/java-io-ioexception-mark-reset-not-supported-java-audio-input-stream-buffered)

I am faced with `java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark` exception with `BufferedInputStream` technique and `java.lang.NullPointerException` excpetion with url technique.
Is there any other technique to overcome the above mentioned exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like java version 7 discontinued supporting older formats and implemented a new software synthesizer Gervill (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u30-relnotes-1394870.html) which has lead to incompatibility between versions 6 and 7(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities)

I had been using java version 6 until now and tried loading currently unsupported formats using java version 7 which likely caused these exceptions